# Sitecore System Lucene Index for custom queries

Tags: lucene, indexing, sitecore

I have been using Sitecore query and FAST query for some sections of the website. But with growing content these queries have gotten slow and I'd like to implement Lucene querying for content to speed up things.

I am wondering if I can just use the System index instead of having to setup a separate index. Does Sitecore by default index all content in the content editor? Is this a good approach or should I just create my own index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm going to assume your using Sitecore 6.4->6.6)

As with everything .. it depends .. Sitecore keeps an index of all the Sitecore items in its system index, you are welcome to use that. Sometimes you may want a more specialised or restricted list of items, like being based on a certain template, being indexed or need a checkbox field indexed (as the system one by default only indexes `text` fields).

Setting up your own search index is pretty easy.. It does require some fiddling with the web.config though (and I'd recommend adding as a `.include` file).

Create an new `<index>` node with its own `id` that will define the name of the collection and the folder it will go into. (You can check its working by looking for the dir in the `/data/indexes` directory of your installation.

[image]

.. next you can tell the crawler which database to look at (most likely `master` if you want unpublished content to be indexed or `web` for published stuff) and where to start the search from (in this example I am indexing only the news section). You can `tag`,`boost`and tell if whether to `IndexAllFields` (otherwise it will only index fields it understands as text .. rich-text / multi-line text / text etc).

[image]

.. Finally, you can tell the indexer which template types to include or exclude.

[image]

How the indexer works is that it will subscribed to item events within sitecore .. so every time an item is changed or moved or deleted the index will be updated automatically. Obviously if you are indexing the `web` db the items will need to have been published.

[image]

More in-depth info on the query syntax & indexing can be found [here on SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Sitecore%20Search%20and%20Indexing.aspx).

The search syntax and API is much improved in 6.4/6.5 but if you want to add extra kick then my colleague Alex Shyba's [Advanced Database Crawler](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/11/sitecore-searcher-and-advanced-database.html) is worth checking out too.

Hope this helps :D

Comment: I've read a little about the AdvancedDatabaseCrawler written by Alex Shyba, especially about the way it handles some of the fields including dates. Would you recommend that? I think the setup is exactly similar to what you described except that some of the code he wrote might be a little different.

Comment: The Advanced crawler has a whole bunch of tweaks and conveniences to make the search easier to work with and fills in some of the holes in the original implementation. Some of that work was taken in  as part of the API refresh for 6.4/6.5 and will continue to get better in later versions. I know a lot of customers who use this and get on very well with it. I think if you cant get what you want from the standard search this is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

You will want to implement your own index.  For the same reason that you are seeing things slow down when there is a lot of content, indexes slow down when there is a lot of content in it as well.

I prefer targeted indexes meant specifically to drive the functionality I need and only has the data in it that is required.  This allows for smaller and more efficient index usage on your components.

Additionally, you probably want to look into the [AdvancedDatabaseCrawler put together by Alex Shyba](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2010/11/sitecore-searcher-and-advanced-database.html).  There are [a few blogs out there](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/tag/advanceddatabasecrawler/) with some great posts on implementing this lucene indexing module.

Answer (score 1):

A separate index is always a wise decision, you can keep it light. In big environments the system index can grow up to gigabytes.

You can exclude the content from the index, as you will only be using it for performing lookups, not showing content from the index.

Finally: the system index is for the master database, you'll be querying the web database, possibly on a content delivery server.